# JavaScript AES Encryption showing wrong result against Java Android

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I try to convert a string using AES method in JavaScript also I only need to use the CryptoJs library to achieve this.

When I try online from this website the result is coming as I expected which my Java program can decrypt it but when I try JavaScript I don't get the same result I get from the website.

This is what I need;

Data: `{"test":1}` 
Secret: `NdRgUkXp2s5v8y/A`

The result should be: `chib8X9Fnr7Vtn4VLRybKg==`

The reason I'm referring the website, I don't know the mode and padding method of the above result but the below result is showing as expected from the server if you know the mode of the above result you can refer that also.

You can refer online encryption using https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption to validate.

This is what I get when I use JavaScript which is wrong;

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('{"test",1}', "NdRgUkXp2s5v8y/A");
console.log(encrypted.toString())
```

Result: `U2FsdGVkX1/GS5CecHJ10Z4qvSP8hY1NkDNtKGlg3OE=`
Also it changes each time when generate.

I use this library https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/

Comment: By the way, why do you use cryptoJS instead of the native Web Crypto API ? got to support IE9 or something ?

Comment: I need to use Postman API testing also

Comment: In Postman it only supports CryptoJS

Comment: More to the point, there are several variants of AES and the result will depend not only on the variant and the key, but on an initialization vector. If any of those parameters is different, you'll get a different cyphertext.

Comment: @Touffy can you write javascript using cryptojs, to get same result as this website https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption

Comment: ECB, 128 is the method

Comment: The documentation clearly states: "For the key, when you pass a string, it's treated as a passphrase and used to derive an actual key and IV.". However, what that actually means may not be clear. Without going into details, it means that you should not use a string for a key. You should use a CryptoJS.lib.WordArray using something like `var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("175345a789abcdef");`

Comment: Why do you need compatibility with some random web site in the first place? Look up standards and test vectors on these standards.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes : The reason I'm referring the website, I don't know the mode and padding method of the above result but the below result is showing as expected from the server if you know the mode of the above result you can refer that also.

Comment: `var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('{"test":1}', CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("NdRgUkXp2s5v8y/A"), {mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB});` reproduces the ciphertext: (1) the key must be parsed with the Utf8-encoder, (2) the ECB mode must explicitly be specified (since the CryptoJS-default is CBC), (3) PKCS7 padding must be used (equals the CryptoJS-default) and (4) there is a typo in the posted code (`,` instead of `:`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the plain string value as a secret instead of UTF-8 encoded text and the value you get from the mentioned website is encrypted using **PKCS7** padding method with **ECB** mode. Usually, this is the method most of the Android Java encryption methods support.

**Encryption** using `CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7` and make sure you provide the secret as `UTF-8` as `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key)` not in plain text.

```
let data = '{"test":1}'
let key = 'NdRgUkXp2s5v8y/A'

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});

console.log(encrypted.toString());
```

**Decryption method**

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted.toString(), CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
})

console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8))
```

The below example proves the encrypted value matches as expected.

```js
let data = '{"test":1}'
let key = 'NdRgUkXp2s5v8y/A'

/*
* Encryption
*/
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});

console.log(encrypted.toString());

/*
* Decryption
*/
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted.toString(), CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
})

console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8) + "\n")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are printing out the decrypted string don't forget to add
.toString(CryptoJs.enc.utf8).

Check https://github.com/brix/crypto-js#plain-text-encryption